# "Рысь": что первично?

Tags: этимология, омонимы

Интересно, какое значение слова "рысь" первично: название аллюра лошади или название дикой кошки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это омонимы.
Одно с другим напрямую не связано.

рысь I I, род. п. -и – животное "lуnх", укр. рись, блр. ры́ся, др.-русск., сербск.-цслав. рысь, болг. рис, сербохорв. ри̏с, род. ри̏са, словен. rȋs м. "рысь", rȋsa, ж. – то же, чеш., слвц. rуs м., польск. ryś м. Связано с чеш. rysý, rysavý "рыжеватый", ryšý, ryšavý – то же, ryšán "рыжеголовый, лиса", слвц. rysý, rysavý "пестрый", польск. rуsаwу, в.-луж., н.-луж. rysy "рыжий", далее родственно ры́жий, руда́, рдеть, ру́сый; см. Маценауэр, LF 17, 193; Штрекель, AfslPh28, 488; Младенов 561; Смешек, Маt. i Рr. 4, 404 и сл. Допустимо также происхождение из *lysь с вторичным r под влиянием* rysъ "рыжий, пятнистый". В последнем случае следовало бы сближать с лит. lū́šis "рысь", лтш. lũsis, др.-прусск. luysis, д.-в.-н. luhs "рысь", греч. λύγξ, арм. lusаnunkΏ мн., ср.-ирл. lug, род. loga "рысь" (см. близкие формы: М.–Э. 2, 520; Педерсен, Kelt. Gr. 1, 186, 188; Хюбшман 454); ср. Траутман, ВSW 164; Гуйер, LF 40, 302. Контаминация с *rysъ могла опираться на мотивы табу; см. Смешек, там же. Менее вероятно истолкование -r- влиянием* rykati (см. ры́кать), вопреки Брандту (РФВ 24, 145), или слова рвать, вопреки Вальде (442). Нельзя доказать заимствование *rysь из ир., вопреки Kоржинеку (LF 67, 289), Янко (LF 40, 302), Зубатому (устное сообщение), поскольку подобное слово до сих пор в ир. не засвидетельствовано. •• [Еще об ир. влиянии см. Мошинский, Zasiąg, стр. 132. – Т.]

II II, ры́сью, рысцо́й (напр., бежать, скакать), укр. ристь, др.-русск. ристiю тв. ед. (сборн. ХV в.; см. Соболевский, Лекции 114). Связано с ристать; -ры- представляет собой диал. развитие -ри-; см. также Преобр. II, 231. Ввиду др.-русск. формы на -и- сомнительно сближение со шв. rusа "бросаться, спешить" и ры́хлый, ру́сло, вопреки Маценауэру (LF 18, 246), Шефтеловицу (KZ 56, 199). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973